# Voting to closing questions because comments are not answered?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes questions cannot be solved because of missing details which are requested by comments. Example:

- [In PEAR After insertion, i am getting insert id, but if i check in table no rows inserted.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517754/in-pear-after-insertion-i-am-getting-insert-id-but-if-i-check-in-table-no-rows)

I asked for more information 6 days ago but the question has not been updated yet. Is it ok to vote for closing because there is not enough information?

Comment: Um... Looks to me like he edited in code and version a half-hour or so after you commented. Were you expecting something else?

Comment: A clear change recognition fail on my side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure; close as "not a real question":

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, **incomplete**, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Comment: Of course, given the age of the question, it's not always likely that four other 3k+ users will come across it; a mod flag might be warranted.